# How exactly is the White House enforcing audio-only briefings?

Tags: united-states, president, government, media

Today, like many days in the past few weeks, the White House Press Briefing with Sean Spicer was audio-only, i.e. no cameras allowed.  My question is, how is this camera ban enforced?  Does Spicer ask the Press Corps to promise to not to record video? Or does the Secret Service prevent the cameramen from entering the briefing room, or what?

I'm basically trying to figure out, what exactly stops a reporter from recording video from his smartphone?

EDIT: In addition to making briefings audio-only, the White House is also restricting when the audio can be released; reporter are not allowed to stream the audio live, instead the audio can only be broadcast after the briefing is over.  Well, today one reporter violated that restriction and streamed the audio live on Periscope; see [this Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2017/07/19/a-reporter-broke-white-house-rules-by-streaming-live-audio-of-an-off-camera-briefing/?tid=sm_tw&utm_term=.d1d03824ec03#comments) for details.  It remains to be seen if this reporter will face any consequences or if other reporters will decide to do the same.

Comment: Not a full answer but I can almost guarantee that if a reporter was caught videotaping such a briefing, while maybe not illegal, they could certainly bet on not being invited back for any other briefings or conferences.

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae Is it possible for the White House to revoke a reporter's press credentials to a White House briefing?  Or is credentialing handled through the White House Correspondents Association?

Comment: To *get* credentials, it's handled by the WHCA.  However, removing credentials and barring a reporter are two different things.  [Here's a 2010 article](https://foreignpolicy.com/2010/06/07/can-the-white-house-revoke-a-reporters-credentials/) on the revocation of credentials.  However, as we've already seen, the Trump administration has already [barred many reporters](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/28/us/politics/white-house-barring-reporters-from-briefings.html) from briefings.  From the second link, "Public officials are not required to give reporters perfectly equal access..."

Comment: Also, it is not as if they were in a dark cave which made it difficult to see what every reporter is doing. And I think the most effective deterrent is that it is not very useful to record the video if you do not publish it later, and as soon as it is published it would be pretty clear who did the recording.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yeah, but I'm not even talking about hiding it.  I'm trying to find out what happen if one of the reporters took out his iPhone and openly said "Sean, I'm recording this."